# Scenekit move object with respect to camera

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I've placed a node in Scenekit/ARKit

Now I want to move node/object to right and left with help of buttons. Issue is when I moves my camera/device and press right button, node moves in direction of axis it was first initiated, Not moves right with respect to camera. How can I achieve this?

current code on tapping right button

```
position.x += 0.2
```

Comment: This is because the Coordinate System of ARKit is placed initial, and then remains static  until you reset the ARSession. You will have to find a solution to determine the angle between the initial position and the current camera positioin. This can be quite tricky.

Comment: Can you please share a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @de. Can you kindly explain what kind of example you require from my side to reproduce? bcz this will happen with every project/node when you change the position of camera.

Comment: I usually create a new Xcode project and drop minimal code in to show the issue, ideally only in one file, and paste the code in the question. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66475284/921573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
guard let front = sceneView.pointOfView?.simdWorldFront else {return}
let horazontalRight = cross(front, simd_float3(0,1,0))
    
// for moving right
node.position +=  SCNVector3(horazontalRight *  0.01)
```

Comment: `extension SCNVector3 {
    static func +=(lhv: inout SCNVector3, rhv: SCNVector3) {
        lhv.x += rhv.x
        lhv.y += rhv.y
        lhv.z += rhv.z
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. Have been fighting with the same problem